# displaying speech data in log scale using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have speech data that I can represent using matlab plot.
however, If i want to display it on log scale(like cooledit or Audition), I can take something like

```
data = audioread(pth);
for j=1:length(data)
    if data(j) >0 
         data(j) = 20*log10(data(j));
    else
         data(j) = 20*log10(abs(data (j)));
    end
end
```

problem with this is that zero values map to infinity and negative values map to positive side . I need representation where Y axis would run in db like [0 -3 ..-21..-inf.. -21 -3 0](like in Cooledit) and the data is plotted as per this axis.
How do i do this?
sedy

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't really make sense to display an instantaneous AC waveform on a log scale - as demonstrated by your results. I googled for cooledit screenshots and found this.

[image]

To accomplish this you would want to keep your data linearly scaled and draw it normally. Then just label the axis at the desired dB points.

Comment: It makes perfect sense and it is done in Audacity as it should be.